# gather session ID and place into a sql query

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a website which uses session ID to gather the customer ID, It is a booking system, once a customer makes a booking I want to create another page so they can see their own bookings. I need help with the actual sql query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your problem? What did you try and what went wrong?

Comment: when a user logs in and a session is created, I want them to be able to click on a link which will show a table of the bookings made, there will be several users makings bookings, I have created a page which show all bookings, but I want a page which only shows the users bookings.

Comment: You can store user bookings in the database against customer ID. Actually, you don't need a session for that. Where is a problem?

Comment: I have a database which uses a customerID, but I only want to show a user their bookings not all the bookings within the database,I need help with the SQL query to show the details of the booking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this SQL query to search in the database from the data that you want, only from the user that matches de Session["customerID"] that you must create when the customer login.

`SELECT column_name FROM customer_table WHERE customerID = $_Session["customerID"]`

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. The next thing is I have done a 3 table join and I need to include the WHERE statement